# Finding more information about Rhode Island grave stone bearing date range 1897-1923?

Tags: united-states, grave-marker, address, rhode-island, portugal

Some ancestors of mine immigrated to the US. Jose Correia in 1915 and afterwards his wife, child and mother-in-law.

It seems his wife died while in labor and afterwards the family came back to Portugal. But his wife was definitely buried in the US.

I have found registers of Jose Correia entering the US, but I didn't find the immigration records of the women that went afterwards.

[I might have found the grave of his wife Maria Lucinda.](https://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=63865203)

They didn't give her surnames in Portugal, most probably because her father was declared unknown. Anyways the date of birth matches exactly the name on the following grave. Maria L. Correia could be Maria Lucinda. This grave is in the Precious Blood Cemetery in Woonsocket, Rhode Island. It seems to be a catholic cemetery and I called the local parish and unfortunately they couldn't say anything about the grave since there was a fire in the 1950s where they lost a lot of records. I also didn't find anything on familysearch.org which I believe has extensive information about vital records of Rhode Island.

[image]

I'm a bit stuck here. How can I find more information about this grave afterwards?(there's nothing online about them) I have his SSN number, I know his address in Woonsocket back then because he was drafted for WWI and WWII. I also know the precise date of Maria Lucinda's birthday and where she was born in Portugal.

List of facts that I have that make me think she is Maria Lucinda:

- From the Portuguese christening record I know Maria Lucinda was born on 30 March 1897. It matches the information on the grave.
- Yes, there are a lot of records for Maria Correia's since these are common Portuguese names. But there aren't much records for Maria Lucinda and the abbreviation on the grave matches her second name (Lucinda).
- It's a known fact in the family that she died in the United States. I know she registered a child in Portugal in January 1916 and that this child also went to the US with Maria Lucinda very early in life.
- Her husband was drafted for WWI and he had an address in Woonsocket in Woonsocket in 1917. So I can expect her to be around Woonsocket in 1923, which is where the grave is located. Here's the registration draft:

[image]

If you want to give me advice about how I can find more information about Maria Lucinda online, I'd like that. But what I'm really asking is which registry or archive I need to reach out for to ask if they know something about this grave.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  When you say "I also didn't find anything on familysearch.org" what exactly does that mean? What did you search, and how?

Comment: hi, I just added more information about her! thank you for your time!

Comment: @JanMurphy I've searched all the possible names and different interval of dates of birth and death.

Comment: So you searched the Historical Records at FamilySearch, but nothing else? Examples: you didn't do a place search, or search the catalog for the name of the cemetery, or look for a book of cemetery transcriptions? *How* did you search -- did you search for individual collections, or did you only do a Global search?

Comment: I searched familysearch.org and ancestry.com extensively. But unfortunately I'm not acquainted with other good websites for death records and cemetery records. Where can I find such records outside familysearch.org? And do you know if it was already required to go to a civil registry to declare death in 1923 in Rhode Island? The problem with this cemetery is that its records were lost in a fire in 1950 like the parish told me.

Comment: @JanMurphy I searched globally, but I tried different approaches. I tried being less specific and afterwards I tried being very specific. The only record about a Maria L. Correia is this grave that someone took a pic of and put on FindAGrave

Comment: by the way, I just researched her name on FindAGrave and there is only one record for Maria Correia that was born in 1897. Precisely the grave I showed a picture from.

Comment: Have you looked for Maria's obituary in a local newspaper? If there's more than just a death notice, the details will probably settle if this Maria is the one you are trying to find.

Comment: I tried to find newspapers from 1923 of Woonsocket, but they are all in French somehow :P

Comment: @PolyGeo Your title edit assumes that a person is actually buried where this stone is placed and when this burial took place, when we have no evidence for either fact.  Stones can be placed at any time and the inscriptions can have errors.  Note that in the British Isles the stones are called "memorial inscriptions", a term I prefer.  Families sometimes place stones as a memorial even though the person is not buried there.

Comment: I didn't know that people placed stones without the accompanying deceased in the grave. I have to disagree with you that there's no evidence this grave is from her. I have a hypothesis that this is indeed her grave  based on evidence that she went to the US, that her husband lived in Woonsocket and the name and birth year on the grave match hers.The death year also gets in the whole picture very well. I'm looking for more ways to find more information about this grave to prove or disprove my hypothesis. The hypothesis itself is a good assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with online databases, especially where the record creator or indexer may have been unfamiliar with the correct spelling of a surname, sometimes it is worth searching just on first name and some other known characteristics alone.

A possibility for Maria L. Correia, for example, might be [this record](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:F84N-GS8). It gives her name as "Marie Lucinda Careau", her husband as Joseph, her parents as Antoine Loffier and Marie Jesus. I can not see any trace of the name "Careau"

The year of birth being 1898 might be simply because the year of birth is not directly recorded on the death certificate but it is a calculation based on her age in 1923. The film number associated with this indexed record is 1940073 which relates to "deaths and index of deaths" microfilmed from documents at

> Westerly, Narragansett, Charlestown, Newport and Woonsocket 1923

Furthermore, with a free login, this film is actually online, despite the image not being linked directly.  A short examination of the deaths for Woonsocket turns up [Marie L. Careau](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-99H7-8S83?i=708&cat=698695) (may require you to log in to view).

Important details from this: this woman was born Portugal, and buried in the Precious Blood Cemetery. Her husband was Joseph and there is an address (18 Jansen Ave), which hopefully you can link back to your family. It also looks to me like her cause of death, though not easily readable, could start with the word puerperal, which would make sense if it was related to childbirth.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. Thank you so very much for your help! You've found it! The photocopied record of return of death says 'Marie' and her parents were from Portuguese origin, so I can safely assume that the medical doctor that wrote this record were mistaken about the names. Woonsocket was also full of French immigrants, which explains how Maria because Marie and Correia because Careau.

Comment: You helped me a lot. I had nothing on her except the grave. Right now there's a very nice person from the area looking obituaries in the Woonsocket Library for me and this was only possible because you gave me the right dates. Again, thank you so very much for your help!

Comment: The already deceased granddaughter of Maria Lucinda Correia, Ester, asked her daughter Ana(my cousin) a lot to search for the grave of Maria Lucinda. Ana didn't know where to start and now we know where Maria Lucinda is buried thanks to you! Now that I have dates I can also start looking for the information about the deceased newborn, which probably died in the same hospital from the return of death record you provided me.

Comment: By the way I tried to search in general terms, but I never thought about trying Marie... only Mary or Maria. Anyways the reason I didn't find it was more because of the very odd last name they gave her in the record. All my searches were based on Correia/Correy/Corey. I simply didn't think about trying French variants of the name.

Comment: Question: the first record you showed me doesn't have an image attached to it. The one with this info: Citing this Record
"Rhode Island Deaths and Burials, 1802-1950," database, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:F84N-GS8 : 6 December 2014), Marie Lucinda Careau, 25 Mar 1923; citing Rhode Island, reference ; FHL microfilm 1,940,073.
I was wondering if I can find this microfilm somewhere. Familysearch.org does give any clue of the whereabouts of this microfilm.

Comment: Look at the second link - 1940073 is online, you will need to sign in.

Answer (score 4):

FindAGrave lists a considerable number of persons named Maria Correia in various graveyards in Rhode Island (as well as in other states). I would be wary of an identification based solely on first and last name and year of birth.

However, together with the other evidence provided in the edits to the original question the identity of the women in the grave with "your" Maria Lucinda is starting to look plausible.

What more do you know about Jose Correia?

It might be worthwhile digging out the 1920 census records for the ward(s) corresponding to the known address(es) of Jose Correia, especially 81 Bernon street. Search by location, not name, since some of the census takers mangled some names pretty badly.

Comment: hi, I just added more information about her in the end of my post! thank you for your time!

Comment: by the way, I just researched her name on FindAGrave and there is only one record for Maria Correia that was born in 1897. Precisely the grave I showed a picture from.

Comment: OK. This is evidence and taken with the other evidence provided in the edits to the original question it is starting to look plausible. It might be worthwhile digging out the 1920 census records, especially for the ward(s) corresponding to the known address(es) of Jose Correia. Search by location, not name, since some of the census takers mangled some names pretty badly.